# How is Firefox Lockwise able to decrypt saved logins without primary password?

Tags: encryption, decryption, firefox

I was wondering how [Firefox Lockwise](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/lockwise/) is able to securely encrypt and decrypt saved logins across devices without using a primary password? As far as I understand, regardless of whether an encryption algorithm is symmetric or asymmetric, a private key is necessary to encrypt and decrypt the data. For instance, I could image how  a primary password (or its derivation) can be used as an encryption/decryption key. But what about the case when no primary password is given? What is used as an encryption/decryption key in such a scenario? What mechanism guarantees that no middle-man is able to decrypt the data (beyond TLS, that is)?

I am aware of the several similar questions that were posted, but I could not find any answers that would focus on this particular scenario.

Just to clarify, I am looking for an accessible, layman's explanation of the protocol/algorithm, rather than a formal, technical one.

Comment: Why are you thinking that there isn't a primary password?

Comment: The answers to the duplicate explain everything and even explain the "primary password" issue. There is one, it's just the device's password.

Comment: "Why are you thinking that there isn't a primary password?" - Because I did not set one up. When I refer to the "primary password", I refer to the specific primary password that encrypts the data locally. With all respect, you have completely failed to comprehend the essence of the question. The remark about "device's password" is especially appalling, since it bears no relevance to the question and it is not used in either of the clients. And the closest explanation I could get in the linked question is reference to "PBKDF2 and HKDF with SHA-256", which was not explained at all.

Comment: But that's how it works. There is a primary password, it's just not one you set. I understand. And the duplicate answers you. I think you are expecting to see something specific in the answers but it's not there. But the duplicate explains how it works, including the link to the Firefox FAQ.

Comment: Just after the line you quote, you have this: "So the encryption key is derived from your Firefox username and password." Is there something else you are looking for?

Comment: The alleged duplicate focuses on how the 3rd party client-side application(Opera) was able to access the data locally without primary password. This is not at all what this question is about.

Comment: "So the encryption key is derived from your Firefox username and password." - Although this sentence is grazing upon the answer, it does not provide a high-level explanation of the process, nor do the following sentences. It in fact yields more questions than answers.

Comment: Yes, the question focuses on something else, yet the *answers* answer you.  And the one sentence is a "layperson's explanation". If you want a higher level explanation, the links ***above*** the line you quoted offers that. That link even goes into very deep explanations of how each part works. So, I'm confused. If all of that doesn't answer you, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: You mention password derivation in your question, which would appear to mean that you understand that process. With the answers and the Firefox link provided, you should have what you need.

Comment: If you don't like the duplicate, then your answer is found in the Lockwise FAQ.: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-firefox-sync-keeps-your-data-safe-even-if-tls-fails

Comment: OK, the link that *you* have provided does seem to answer my question. So if I understood correctly, the Lockwise doesn't handle encryption, but rather it is left up to Sync to encrypt the data using a hashed password. I assume for this to work, a hashed password has to be stored on device (as opposed to some session ID). Technically that makes the premise of my question wrong, which should be the real answer. But again, it is not a duplicate of the pinned question. Nevertheless, I thank you for the link to that Firefox support page. I did not find it because I was asking the wrong question.

Comment: But ideally this should've been a dedicated answer, since I was under the impression that quality answers on SE network are supposed to have at least some degree of explanation, rather than a mere link to external source.

Comment: Actually that still leaves this question partially unanswered. On mobile devices one could use QR code to log into Firefox Sync. If one never enters the password, how is Firefox on mobile able to decrypt the data? Would this sub-question be considered a duplicate as well?